# Do these verbs have the same meaning : help / help out

Tags: meaning, word-difference

There are many verbs that have different meanings when we add a preposition to them, whish are the phrasal verbs -according to what I understand- , but sometimes I can't feel the difference , like : end up , help out, miss out

Is there really a difference that I can't see ? or they're almost the same without the preposition ?

Comment: There absolutely *is* a difference (as any good dictionary should be able to tell you), but listing all examples or coming up (<- see?) with a rule is too broad.

Comment: @Stephie i see , I'll look for them in a dictionary, thank you

Comment: Just a tiny example what I mean: Take the verb [*make*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1?q=Make), compare it with the phrasal verb [*make up*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make-up_2?q=Make+up) and you'll immediately see why you need to learn them individually. Once you start to master phrasal verbs, you have made good progress in really learning the English language.

Comment: ...similarly [*make out*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make-out?q=make+out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only using your examples and keeping the definitions very narrow because @Stephie is completely right:

`To end` means to finish or complete something.

`To end up` means to to become something.

Examples:

"I want this to end."  means the speaker wants whatever action is occuring to stop.

"I want to end up like Michael Jordan."  Means I want to become something (a skilled sportsman, or famous, or wealthly) like Michael Jordan already is.

---

`To help` means to give assistance or to join with others to complete a task.

`To help out` is, for all intent and purpose, identical to `to help`.

---

`To miss` means to fail to achieve a goal or expectation, or to fail to arrive at an expected destination.

`To miss out` means to lose (miss) an opportunity.

---

How a phrasal verb relates to the original verb has more to do with the culture that caused its creation than any rule.  My favorite comes from the 1970's.

`A freak` is someone or something unusual or abnormal.

`To freak` is to act unusually or abnormally... *except...*

`To freak out` is to suddenly act abnormally or wildly.

The exception I noted is that it's become common in spoken English to use the verb `to freak` as a short form of `to freak out`.  Because it's uncommon for a phrasal verb to be used before it's parent verb, this is likely an example of an original verb falling into disuse, then being picked up again for another purpose.

Living languages... you've gotta love them.